# How to display the nested attributes in the index action in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

My activeadmin club resource file is: 
clubs.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Club do
  permit_params :name, :email, :admin_id,
club_profile_attributes: [
  :id, :club_id, :logo, :address_1, :address_2, :city,
  :state, :country_id, :latitude, :longitude, :website, :email,
  :fiscal_number, :phone_number_1, :phone_number_2]
  index do
    selectable_column
    column :id
    column :name
    column :admin
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    actions
  end
```

I want to display the club profile attributes in my above file in the index action.
The relationship is:
club has_one :club_profile

Answer (score 1):

What (all the attributes? only some?) and how (one for each column? everything on the same column?) do you want to show?

Check the docs https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html

If you add `column: :club_profile`, ActiveAdmin will try some methods to retrieve the value in this order: `:display_name, :full_name, :name, :username, :login, :title, :email, :to_s`

If you want to specify how to retrieve the value, you can pass a block:

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column "Profile logo" do |club|
    image_tag club.club_profile.logo
  end
end
```

If you want multiple columns then I guess you'll have to use a custom block for each column.